# Failed to sync Gradle project 'My Application'

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error in my laptop's Android Studio but at my workplace, when I use same SDK with the same project, it's perfectly fine. I tried reinstalling Android Studio deleting .gradle folder but error still persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would go to SDK Manager,  check API 23 (SDK Platforms), uninstall it and then re-download it. And make sure everything in SDK Tools tab are up-to-date.

Comment: it fixed it by deleting all ".filename" folders in my User directory. Uninstalling it didn't remove it in the first place. I think the program fetches an old data from those folders. Deleting them will force Android Studio to create a fresh ones.

Comment: Uninstalling Android Studio doesn't remove the external SDK folders, no